# Is there a java call to get the number of threads which pthread_create uses?

Tags: java, pthreads, java-threads

I am getting an out of memory error in my Java application:

```
 Failed to start thread - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 0k, detached.
```

This looks like a the number of threads is large (stack size: 1024k). Is there a java call to get such a value? I tried both ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getThreadCount() and Thread.activeCount(); but those are returning threadCountMxBean=49 and activeCount=35, which is naturally very far from 1024k. Does anyone know how to get the true number of threads that the system is using?

Comment: I *think* all Java memory comes from a common pool.  So if memory is being used up elsewhere, then just a few threads could push it over the top and result in an OOM error.  So it's possible that there are in fact only a few threads in the system.  But take that with a grain of salt.

Comment: Thank you @markspace . I am using maven openJdk15 which is https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven/blob/bdffb5117c33476d554325d8efe5866306004b99/openjdk-15/Dockerfile and is based off of 'openjdk:15-jdk-oraclelinux8'. I ssh'd into the docker container but cannot execute ps. Do you know of another such command?

Comment: "stacksize: 1024k" does not speak to any thread count.  It is the size of the stack requested for one thread.

Comment: Thank you @JohnBollinger . So, just to check my understanding - the pthread_create was requesting 1024k stack size but that call failed, is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's what the diagnostic is saying.  It may nevertheless be that the error results from one of a couple different limits on the number of processes or threads being reached, but the message does not say that specifically, nor does it provide any details relevant to such a conclusion.